# Associating a form with a user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have posted here a few times, on various aspects about on application. It's a property app.

I have a Landlord, and Tenant profiles. In this scenario, I'm logged into a Landlord account. I'm currently viewing a prospective tenants profile. I click a button called "Start Tenancy" which redirected me to a from. I want to populate this form with the name of the tenant I just clicked on. How would I go about this?

Currently clicking this button sends me to a form, but I don't know to associate it with the user whose page I was just on. Is it as simple as using the id.

The controller that links to form

```
public function tenancyIndex(){

    return view('/pages/account/tenancy/create');
  }
```

Create form view.

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <div class="row">
  <div class="row mt-2">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label for="landlord-name">Landlord Name</label>
    </div> <!-- ./col=6 -->
  </div> <!-- ./ row-4-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <select class="form-control" name="landlord-name">
        <option >Landlord Name</option>
      </select>
    </div> <!-- ./ row 3-->
  </div> <!-- ./col-3 -->
  <div class="row mt-2">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label for="tenant-name">Tenant Name</label>
    </div> <!-- ./col=6 -->
  </div> <!-- ./ row-4-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <select class="form-control" name="tenant-name">
        <option>Tenant Name</option>
      </select>
    </div> <!-- ./ row 3-->
  </div> <!-- ./col-3 -->
  <button class="mt-2 btn btn-primary" type="submit">Create Watchlist</button>
</form> <!-- ./form -->
```

I have profiles set up already. I'm not sure if I should post that. This is a method in the same controller that opens up the profile page.

```
  public function index($id){
   //Authenticated different user types
   //Sends Landlord and Tenant to appropiate pages

   $user = User::where('id', $id)->first();
   $properties = PropertyAdvert::where('user_id', $id)->get();
   $property = WatchedProperties::all();
   $Watchlists = Watchlists::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
   $users = Auth::user();
   $tenancies = $users->tenancies();
   $tenancyRequests = $users->tenacyRequests();

  return view('/pages/account/index', compact('properties', 'user', 'Watchlists', 'property', 'tenancyRequests', 'tenancies', 'Watchlists'));
}
```

The accounting view is then different depending on if you're a landlord or tenant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Create Start Tenancy button url should look like this `pages/account/tenancy/create/1`

Where 1 is the id of the tenant 
Now when the landlord will click on this button or link.So on the form page you can get the id from the route and get the tenant details from the DB and fill the form accordingly

Answer (score 0):

in view {{$user->name}} should show the user name based on the url, i think im not too sure as i am a beginner myself